# What is the reason for this connection error on google cloud firestore-php?

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following the official docs to setup google cloud firestore to integrate with my php project

[1] https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers

when I initialize the `FirestoreClient` I get the following error

```
Error rendering 'projects/{project=*}/databases/{database=*}': expected binding 'project' to match segment '{project=*}', instead got null\n
Provided bindings: Array\n
(\n
    [project] => \n
    [database] => (default)\n
)\n
```

First In the documentation it tells to use ENV VARIABLE though using the following command
`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/user/Desktop/programming/workarea/.firebase.config.json`

I investigated a lot and I think the problem happens when the library tries to establish a connection with the firestore server.

I couldn't find the root of the problem. but I think for some reason the php server not reading the env vars so it's not able to establish a proper connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled some time with this too, resolved it after realizing this: as said [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/master/AUTHENTICATION.md), you first have to authenticate. For that, install the gcloud-sdk [available here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/), then follow the steps provided.

Second, you have to set your environment variable with the path to your project's credentials file, as you were doing, in the bash (i use `~/.bashrc`), exit the terminal and reenter it (**necessary**, as it may not apply the file edit for that terminal session). You could also type `source .bashrc` to apply changes without closing the terminal.

Then you should be fine, assuming you have the other required environment dependencies installed [found here](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.6.2/firestore/readme).